# Can anyone explain why linebreaks make return statements undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This has been the source of my pain for many hours. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

```
function x(){
    return //when there's a line break it doesn't work
    2;
};

alert(x());

function y(){
    return 4; //when there's no line break it works 
};

alert(y());

//Can anyone explain this?
```

I always thought that JavaScript didn't care about line breaks. If you have links to ECMA official documentation on this, I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: in js the break is the end of statement. If you want more than one statement in a line - u should use ';'

Comment: @katrin — No. Line breaks will only sometimes end a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the ECMAScript rules for [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9). The relevant section is:

> When a continue, break, return, or throw token is encountered and a LineTerminator is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the continue, break, return, or throw token.

In short, your code is parsed as if it were:

```
return;
2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most other languages, JavaScript tries to "fix" your code by adding semicolons where it thinks you have forgotten them.

Return statements are such a case - if there is a linebreak after a return statement, it will be interpreted as return;

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript treats a endline after `return` as if there was an `;`
So in:

```
return 
2;
```

`2;` is unreachable code.

And a sole `return` in JavaScript returns `undefined`. Like a function without a `return` does.

Answer (score 0):

JS gramma from mozilla
http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/grammar14.html#N-Statement

Note:

`the OptionalSemicolon grammar state can sometimes reduce to «empty»`